# How to compare all values with other values from same array in php?

Tags: php, arrays

Have PHP any function to compare all values with all other values in an array?

Comment: Show us some code, about what you have tried and want to achieve, we are not clairvoyants.

Answer (score 2):

array_diff, array_intersect

Look at PHP manual and "See also"